# Can you change your email name without making a new account

Tags: iphone

I was wondering can you change the name on your email with out having to make a new account ? For example my email is kendrabarry@icloud.com and I'd like to change it to My married name but I don't want to make a new account and have to send it out everywhere..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new iCloud email alias. Here is the guide from Apple: https://support.apple.com/kb/ph2622

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.